# Issue migrating DB from Local to Heroku Django

Tags: python, django, git, heroku

I've been working on a Django application and have recently run into a few issues pushing updates and migrating DB settings from Local to Heroku.

I followed these steps:

1. I added a few columns to my app model.
2. Then ran `python manage.py makemigrations`
3. then `python manage.py migrate`.
4. I then committed these updates via github.
5. Then I ran `git push heroku master` w/ Heroku CLI
6. Then I entered `heroku run python manage.py migrate`

Unfortunately, this did not migrate the appropriate updates I made to the DB settings in my local dev environment. The error message I received is "Column x does not exist in X-app".
I ended up reverting back to my previous settings in model.py temporarily, but I would like to eventually add new columns to my database.

At this point, I'm trying to assess what the best solution is to the problem. I've reviewed several other Stack Overflow questions, but haven't found one that's worked for me yet. What's odd is that I was able to migrate successfully in previous Heroku deployments.

Any tips anyone has would be extremely appreciated. For reference, I'm using Python 3.6.2 and Django 1.11

```
Traceback:

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
64. return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

The above exception (column courts_court.draft does not exist
LINE 1: ...urts_court"."address", "courts_court"."location", 
"courts_co...) was the direct cause of the following exception:

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
149. response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
147. response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/app/courts/views.py" in court_list
128.    return render(request, "court_list.html", context)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/shortcuts.py" in render
67. template_name, context, request=request, using=using)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/django/template/loader.py" in render_to_string
97. return template.render(context, request)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/django/template/backends/django.py" in render
95. return self.template.render(context)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/django/template/base.py" in render
206. return self._render(context)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
197. return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/django/template/base.py" in render
988. bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
955. return self.render(context)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
173.return compiled_parent._render(context)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
197.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/django/template/base.py" in render
988.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
955. return self.render(context)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
69. result = block.nodelist.render(context)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/django/template/base.py" in render
988. bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
955. return self.render(context)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/django/template/defaulttags.py" in render
168.len_values = len(values)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/django/core/paginator.py" in __len__
117. return len(self.object_list)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/django/db/models/query.py" in __len__
240. self._fetch_all()

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/django/db/models/query.py" in _fetch_all
1074. self._result_cache = list(self.iterator())

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/django/db/models/query.py" in __iter__
52. results = compiler.execute_sql()

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in execute_sql
852. cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
79. return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
64. return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/django/db/utils.py" in __exit__
95. six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/django/utils/six.py" in reraise
685. raise value.with_traceback(tb)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
64. return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

Exception Type: ProgrammingError at /courts/
Exception Value: column courts_court.draft does not exist
LINE 1: ...urts_court"."address", "courts_court"."location", 
"courts_co...`
```

Comment: It sort of depends on where you got the error, do you get it on the migration? Or after running that migration and on a request?

Comment: @kevswanberg I received the error after making the commit to Heroku and running heroku run python manage.py migrate

Comment: What's the output of the push to heroku. Is the app built with no issue?

Comment: @dstrants The app in question receives an error message once I try to migrate with the migrations made locally (which I committed with Git). The error message says there's a db column that does not exist

Comment: You need to show the full error. Usually this is caused by defing a query at module or class level rather than inside a function, so it is called before the migration has a chance to run.

Comment: @DanielRoseman here's the error I received: 

 File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column "updated" of relation "courts_court" does not exist

I tried running migrations a few diff times afterward. It worked locally, but when I pushed to Heroku I still ended up having the same issue.

Comment: That's not the full traceback. You need to post the whole thing, as an edit to the question.

Comment: You still need to post the full traceback otherwise we cannot help you.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Ok thank you. I just added the full traceback to the original question.

Comment: I thought this was supposed to be an error you got when you ran migrate?

Comment: @DanielRoseman it is. I ran makemigrations and migrate locally, which worked without an error. I ran a git commit and then pushed to Heroku. After I pushed to Heroku, I tried running migrate and received the error messages.

Comment: @kevswanberg Would you recommend I connect to my database directly with heroku pg:psql and create those columns that way? I still haven't figured out why they weren't created when I migrated locally and synced w/heroku cli.

Comment: Is that error there in the migrate command? It looks kind of like it is from a request. You could use that utility to inspect to see if the migration was actually run, if not figure out what to do to get it to run on heroku.

Comment: @kevswanberg yes, I received this error after running migrations locally and syncing the app code w/heroku cli + migrating those changes w/ `heroku run python manage.py migrate`.

Comment: @kevswanberg I ended up having to reset my database, and reran `heroku run python manage.py migrate` which worked. I lost all my data but luckily it was all dummy data. So strange...I'm not sure what else I could've done.